# Stopping Travis-CI and AppVeyor from running at same time

Tags: continuous-integration, integration-testing, travis-ci, appveyor

So I have continuous integration going on on my github for an open source project.

For this project I have determined I want to run integration tests,
as part of CI.

Now because the integration tests use a single limited resource,
I can't have more than one running at a time.

So I have set both AppVeyor and Travis to each only run one build/test at a time.
But they don't know about each other.

What is the smart way to handle this situation?

My current thoughts for a work around is to get a second instance of the limitted reasoure, so I can have both at once.
But that is kinda expensive; (for certain values of expense).

Comment: You can use some sort of external "global" mutex (lock). This can be an external Redis cache or AWS S3 storage item or simple Web API service hosted for free on Azure web sites.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Appveyor REST API (https://www.appveyor.com/docs/api/projects-builds/#get-project-last-build) to make Travis wait for Appveyor build to finish. Here is sample in PowerShell (I understand PowerShell is not native for Travis, but this is easiest way for me to create and test the sample).

```
$token = '<your_api_token>'
$headers = @{
  "Authorization" = "Bearer $token"
  "Content-type" = "application/json"
}

while ((Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'https://ci.appveyor.com/api/projects/<your_account)namr>/<your_project_slug>' -Headers $headers  -Method Get).build.status -eq "running") {
    write-host "waiting for Appveyor build to stop running"
    Start-sleep 1
}
```

So if you put something like this before Travis tests execution it should prevent from concurrent access to your limited resource. 
Also it would be a good idea to add one more condition to stop waiting after some time even if it is still in `running` status to prevent things from stuck forever.

Finally I believe that you can do other way around -- make Appveyor wait for Travis to finish build. I just not familiar with Travis API to provide you with example.

Thank you,
Ilya.